# Rodapé não acompanha layout do site e não fica responsivo

Tags: html5, css3, layout-responsivo, footer

Galera, boa tarde.

Estou com dificuldades de deixar o rodapé responsivo, ele não acompanha a página. Conseguem auxiliar através desse código que fiz? 
(Tentei implementar algumas dicas que achei por aqui mas não deu certo)

Grato.

```css
/*Edição do rodape (Footer)*/
footer {
 background-image: url(../img/fundo-rodape.png);
 clear: both;
 padding: 20px 0;
}

footer .container {
 position: relative;
 width: 900px;
}

.social{
 position: absolute;
 top: 12px;
 right: 0;
}

.social li{
 float: left;
 margin-left: 25px;
}

.social a{
 /*tamanho da imagem*/
 height: 32px;
 width: 32px;
 
 /*image replacement*/
 display: block;
 text-indent: -9999px;
}

.social a[href*="facebook.com"]{
 background-image: url(../img/facebook.png);
}

.social a[href*="twitter.com"]{
 background-image: url(../img/twitter.png);
}

.social a[href*="plus.google.com"]{
 background-image: url(../img/googleplus.png);
}
/*Edição do rodape (Footer)*/
```

```html
 <footer>
            <!-- Conteúdo do rodapé --> 
   
   <div class="container">
    <img src="img/logo-rodape.png" alt="Logo Mirror Fashion">
    
    <ul class="social">
     <li><a href="http://facebook.com/mirrorfashion">Facebook</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://twitter.com/mirrorfashion">Twitter</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://plus.google.com/mirrorfashion">Google+</a></li>
    </ul>
    
   </div>
 </footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É porque você definiu uma largura fixa na `<div class="container">`, assim ela nunca irá acompanhar a largura da tela, porque terá sempre a largura de `900px`.

Em vez de colocar `width: 900px;`, altere para `width: 100%;` e coloque `max-width: 900px;` e `width: 100%;` no `<footer>`:

```
footer {
    background-image: url(../img/fundo-rodape.png);
    clear: both;
    padding: 20px 0;
   background-color: red;
    max-width: 900px;
   width: 100%;
}

footer .container {
    position: relative;
   width: 100%;
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
/*Edição do rodape (Footer)*/
footer {
 background-image: url(../img/fundo-rodape.png);
 clear: both;
 padding: 20px 0;
   background-color: red;
 max-width: 900px;
   width: 100%;
}

footer .container {
 position: relative;
   width: 100%;
}

.social{
 position: absolute;
 top: 12px;
 right: 0;
}

.social li{
 float: left;
 margin-left: 25px;
}

.social a{
 /*tamanho da imagem*/
 height: 32px;
 width: 32px;
 
 /*image replacement*/
 display: block;
 text-indent: -9999px;
}

.social a[href*="facebook.com"]{
 background-image: url(../img/facebook.png);
}

.social a[href*="twitter.com"]{
 background-image: url(../img/twitter.png);
}

.social a[href*="plus.google.com"]{
 background-image: url(../img/googleplus.png);
}
/*Edição do rodape (Footer)*/
```

```html
<footer>
            <!-- Conteúdo do rodapé --> 
   
   <div class="container">
      <img src="img/logo-rodape.png" alt="Logo Mirror Fashion">
      
      <ul class="social">
         <li><a href="http://facebook.com/mirrorfashion">Facebook</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://twitter.com/mirrorfashion">Twitter</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://plus.google.com/mirrorfashion">Google+</a></li>
      </ul>
      
   </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Certo, eu tirei largura fixa e ficou ok quando executa no mobile, mas desktop continua, a margem ultrapassa o layout, entende?

Comment: Editei a resposta. Veja se era isso.

Comment: Agora o rodapé ficou no tamanho correto, porém ainda ele não alinha. Não consigo postar foto mas vou tentar explicar. Meu site tem um padrão de 940px (esse padrão foi solicitado), então ele não ocupa 100% da tela, o rodapé agora está correto fixo em baixo e o tamanho correto, porém ele distorce a página devido não centralizar junto ao resto do layout. Deu pra entender? Agradeço desde já sua ajuda.

Comment: Coloca `margin: 0 auto;` no footer.

Comment: Cara, ia comentar isso agora, um amigo sugeriu isso também e deu certo. Agradeço muito a ajuda. Valeu !!!

Comment: Show de bola!!!